# Windows 10 using up my bandwidth even with update sharing deactivated

Tags: windows-10, bandwidth, privacy

The "**system**", "**cortana**" and, specially, "**service host: network service**" processes keep using up my bandwidth. I want to prevent windows 10 from using it or at least limit the amount of it that it is allowed to use. I have already disabled the sharing of updates.

I would have included pictures and a more detailed description of my problem, but this page doesn't allow this with my current reputation.

Comment: what do you guys say, do I install Linux?

Comment: You can always write links to pictures and write a more detailed description regardless of reputation. At the moment it is impossible to answer. How much do they use? And installing Linux has nothing to do with it and is also opinion based.

Comment: impossible to answer? I am asking you for a way to prevent windows from using up my bandwidth, what other information do you need? they use anywhere between 0.1 MB/s to 0.5 MB/s, you should be able to answer without that information. And Linux is not related to the topic, just trying to conversate a little.

Comment: seriously considering linux right now, windows 10 is annoying me really hard, probably because I am a little bit of a "power user". D:

Comment: @MatiasChara If that's all you want, then disable network. You said yourself you have more information, so why not share it?

Comment: set your connection as metered an in he settings app you can sometime prevent windows to use metered connections for some action.